# What is the Toaru Kagaku no Railgun manga release schedule?

Tags: manga-production, a-certain-scientific-railgun

Very recently, the Toaru Kagaku no Railgun manga series resumed after its break with Chapter 71/72 (They kinda messed with the chapter numbers, weird).

I've tried to search for a release schedule, but couldn't find one. The official site is Japanese, and I haven't found it there either.

So when does chapter 73 come out? Is there an official release schedule somewhere?

Comment: 71 was the last chapter before the hiatus. The manga resumed with chapter 72 in the October issue (8/27) as noted in Chapter 71.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ It's already resumed. I read the latest today. But what happens next?

Comment: 8/27 is when the next chapter was released. 71 was a epilogue that included the bonfire dance. Which latest chapter are you referring to? The Indian poker one was chapter 72.

Comment: According to chapter 72 the next chapter comes out on the Dec. issue on 10/27.

Comment: It was delayed for the author was under Mugen Tsukuyomi. LOL